Rollback in a classic release Azure Pipeline
My actual deployment will be from stage1 to stage2. Now I want to be able to rollback stage1 if there is an error or rollback on stage2 if stage1 passes and stage2 does not. I added stage3 as a way to rollback if stage1 fails but I didn't see how to run only stage3 if stage1 fails.
Better still is there something I can do to add a rollback step as task in stage1 if an error happens then it should run the rollback steps?
What I  want to do:

First I added a rollback task right in stage1 at the bottom so if any actual task fails it should run the rollback tasks but there was a problem since I have a function that does substitution and so it does not find a value for substitution since the repo is not redownloaded in the same stage.
But if there was a way for me to redownload the repo in the same stage my problem would be solve since the substitution is done in the yaml files from the repo.

As suggested in my answer below, you can try to call the REST API to trigger  Stage3 for Rollback when Stage1 is failed. @Marccelus Enoh

Unless you have one or more good reasons to do an automatic rollback, have you considered adding a manual stage like this?

Clicking on the Pre-deployment conditions icon on the left side of the stage:

The good thing about manual rollbacks is that you have full control over if and when the rollback is performed.

You can try to configure the release pipeline like as below to automatically trigger Stage3 when Stage1 is failed:

On the "Pre-deployment conditions" of Stage3, select its trigger type as "Manual only".


In Stage1, add the job "Detect Failed Deployment" as the last one that is after the deployment job. Enable the option "Allow scripts to access the OAuth token" on this job. And select its condition as "Only when a previous job has failed".


In "Detect Failed Deployment" job, add a PowerShell task (name it "Trigger Stage3 for Rollback") with the following configurations.

Map the environment variable 'SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN' and pass the value of '$(System.AccessToken)' to it.


Add below Inline script to the task.
$organization = "{organization name}"
$project = "$(System.TeamProject)"
$releaseId = $(Release.ReleaseId)
$headers = @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}

# Get the environmentId of Stage3 in current release.
$get_release_uri = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/release/releases/${releaseId}?api-version=7.0"
$get_release = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $get_release_uri -Headers $headers
$Stage3 = $get_release.environments | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "Stage3" }
$envId_Stage3 = $Stage3.id

# Trigger Stage3 via updating it to 'inProgress' status in current release.
$update_env_uri = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/Release/releases/${releaseId}/environments/${envId_Stage3}?api-version=7.0"
$update_env_body = @{status = "inProgress"} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5
$update_env = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $update_env_uri -Method PATCH -Body $update_env_body -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers
Write-Host ($update_env | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 15)




Go the Security hub of the release pipeline and ensure the following two identities has the "Manage deployments" permission set to "Allow".

Project Collection Build Service ({Organization Name})
{Project Name} Build Service ({Organization Name})





